# Save user progress while reading a document. Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, view, save, doc

I have a table with pdf documents. When a document is opened, the user switches to a view which has a custom class (PDFView).

It is necessary to save the last place to read the user's document at the click of a button.

View controller code where the document is read.

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

var nameFile:String?
var titleChapter:String?
class pdfView: UIViewController {


    //save progress doc
    @IBAction func SaveScrollAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
    {
        let  dest =   pdfDocView.currentDestination
    pdfDocView.go(to: dest!)

    }
    //Pdf view
    @IBOutlet var pdfDocView: PDFView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.title = titleChapter
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5326591512, green: 0, blue: 0.002649205323, alpha: 0.8)

        //name Documents for view
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: nameFile,  ofType:"pdf") {
            if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) {
                pdfDocView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
                pdfDocView.autoScales = true
                pdfDocView.displayDirection = .vertical
                pdfDocView.document = pdfDocument
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem? What prevents you from implementing the feature that you described? Do you need to know how to get the current position in a PDF document? Wondering how to save the state?

Comment: I need to save the last user location in the document. If it was saved and left the document on the seventh page, then the next time you open the same document, show the seventh page.

Comment: Yes, I understand the requirement. I'm asking what your specific question is. What specific problem is preventing you from writing code that saves the last user location?

Comment: I tried using the currentDestination property.
And it saves, but only at the first press.
(if I saved the seventh page in the first document)
Further, when I try to save it in another document, it simply flips to the seventh page in the same document.
I don’t know how I can save the user’s position in each document separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use the property `currentDestination`, should contain the current page and location. To set the destination object in your PDFView, use the method `go(to destination: PDFDestination)`.

You can save the object using the regular storage solutions.

[Apple PDFKit Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview/)

Comment: I edited the action buttons. But this does not work as I expected.
At the first press, it saves where I was (for example, the third page in the document), then when I go to this dock and click on the button, it goes to the place where I was saved.
If I click in another document, it jumps to the page where I was saved before. And for this I can save the location only once.
What have I done wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood the issue. However, you should save the current state (let say the current page) for each document, meaning, when saving the `PDFDestination ` object you need to associate that object to a specific document identifier and only load when needed. 

It seems to me that you're saving the destination, and every document opened is loading the same object.

Comment: Yes, you wrote everything correctly. Thanks. I will try now

Comment: Awesome! Let me know if you need more help 

Comment: I just can’t do it right. To be stored separately for each document.
So far, the same result, saves the same value for all arguments.
Could you show how to implement this correctly?

Comment: Well, first you need to find a way to identify your document, like for instance using `document.hashValue` (`PDFDocument` conforms to `Hashable` so you can generate a hash value).
Now create a dictionary that stores your hashes and `PDFDestination` objects: `var documentLastDestinations: [Int: PDFDestination] = [:]`.
Every time you exit a document you need to write `documentLastDestinations[document.hashValue] = destinationObject`
Wehn you load a new doc, search the dicitonary `let destination = documentLastDestinations[document.hashValue]`

Comment: I've had the high-level implementation, remember to store the `documentLastDestinations` in a base controller that manages your document list and he should be responsible to save and load the destinations and give them to the document detail pages.
The communication between the controllers could be done by injection, delegates.... 
Now if you want, save your dictionary in any offline storage